# Ember: Jquery UI sortable and removeObject

Tags: ember.js

I am having an issue when attempting to delete a record after it's been sorted. I have a document model that relates to questions (hasMany). In the view, the user has the ability to drag and drop the questions into a different order. If they click on the delete button, it should remove the question from the view. If the user has re-ordered the list, nothing happens in the view when they click the delete button.

I have seen an [example](http://nerdyworm.com/blog/2013/04/26/ember-dot-js-drag-and-drop-sorting-with-jquery-sortable/) where a list of items is contained in an `ArrayController` along with the use of `beginPropertyChanges()` and `endPropertyChanges()`. I'm not sure if my issue is due to the fact that it is inside an `ObjectController` (a single model contains many items), but I also tried `propertyWillChange()` and `propertyDidChange()`. If I log the model after the user has clicked the delete button I see that the related question has been removed. However, the view is not updating.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    updateSortOrder: function(idx, order) {
        var index = parseInt(idx);
        var question = this.get('model.questions').findBy('idx', index);

        this.propertyWillChange('model.questions');

        if( ! Ember.isEmpty(question)) {
            question.set('order', order);
        }

        this.propertyDidChange('model.questions');
    },


    removeQuestion: function(question) {
        this.propertyWillChange('model.questions');
        this.get('model.questions').removeObject(question);
        this.propertyDidChange('model.questions');
    },

    ...
});



// controller template
{{#each question in model.questions itemController="documents/question-item"}}
    <div class="nf-item" {{bind-attr data-order="question.order" data-idx="question.idx"}}>
    ...
    </div>
{{/each}}


// item controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['documents/create'],

    actions: {
        remove: function() {
            var controller = this.get('controllers.documents/create');
            controller.removeQuestion(this.get('content'));
        }
    }
});


// controller's view
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    sortable: function() {
        var controller = this.get('controller');

        this.$(".nf-sortable").sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                $('.nf-item').each(function(index) {
                    controller.updateSortOrder($(this).attr('data-idx'), index);
                });
            }
        });
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```